# list all Computer names that are under domain

Tags: powershell, active-directory, rdp

The machine I'm trying to RDP does not respond so I'm trying to find another one to connect to but I dont know the names of machines. I was trying to guess the name but I only found 1 and that does not have rdp enabled. Is there a way to list all Computer names that are under domain? 
Is that even possible If I'm just VPN into the domain and I'm not AD admin?

Edit:
while digging around a year later, I stumble upon fun command that will list all machines names connected to a domain. I post it here if anybody need this. type in cmd

```
net view
```

Comment: You should ask your network administrators for the proper information. Digging around a corporate network isn't very intelligent without permission...

Comment: You have received two answers to this question. Why are you saying that "no body is answering me"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$AD = [adsisearcher]"objectcategory=computer"
$Computers = $AD.FindAll()
$Computers.Properties.Name
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this as you only need read only permissions to active directory to get this info:

```
get-adcomputer -filter *
```

Comment: that is not the question - the question I am answering is "Is there a way to list all Computer names that are under domain?".  ...furthermore this command does not scan the network, it only queries active directory

Comment: @stevieb this isn't "scanning" the network, this is no different to opening Outlook and looking at the Global Address List of people you could email. Although this answer will not work without the remote administration tools, I think, most desktops won't have the ActiveDirectory module.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler  Thankyou!  ..and you make a good point :-)

Comment: Thank you for the response when i run this command from powershellI get this get-adcomputer : Unable to find a default server with Active Directory Web Services running. does this mean I can use this command because AD does not have it enabled?

Comment: In  most environments that service is enabled on at least one domain controller in the domain so you can run that command.  So try TessellatingHeckler suggestion   `$AD = [adsisearcher]"objectcategory=computer"
$Computers = $AD.FindAll()
$Computers.Properties`  (I left off name as I wasn't getting any results unless I indexed into properties)